# Delay re-enabling a button using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i have this small code snippet and i'm trying to figure out how to get it to work. Basically what it does is when the button is clicked, it becomes disabled. At the same time it runs a timeout function that will re-enable the button after 3 seconds. I can't figure out how to get it to work! Everything else in the button function works fine except for this. I didn't post the entire code cause it's a lot. Variables are all declared and what not.

```
$("input[type=button]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
var enable_attk = function() {
    $("input[type=button]").attr("enabled", "enabled");     
    enable_timer = setTimeout(enable_attk, 3000);
}

        enable_attk();
```

Comment: One thing - instead of using `attr` for disabling, use `prop`: `$("selector").prop("disabled", true);`

Comment: Here's an example of how I'd do it: http://jsfiddle.net/EN9r3/

Comment: @Ian is there anything wrong with using attr? Will it cause problems in the code or is using prop just a more appropriate way to code this?

Comment: It's easier just to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Comment: @Ian ok nice, i just changed it over. Thanks for the help =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("input[type=button]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
setTimeout(function(){
    $("input[type=button]").removeAttr("disabled");     
}, 3000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zDDbR/